# Select implementation class based on database

Tags: mysql, oracle, dao

I have application which runs on MySQL, now i want to test my app. on oracle DB. This application uses spring, hibernate and jpa. I want to know how to achieve this in same code base with configuration changes in spring.xml or etc.,

Also I have created set of implementation classes for oracle, but don’t know how to tell my Dao to use oracle implementation instead MySQL.

Comment: If you use Hibernate, this will be taken care of for you, minus having to slightly tweak a configuration file specifying which JDBC driver to use.

Answer (score 0):

You use to choice DB. same code base with configuration change your define file in DataSource and JPA entityManagerFactory.

**datasource**

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
    <!--    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property> -->
        <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"></property>
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>
        <property name="password" value="1234"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mariadb://"></property>
    </bean>
```

**entityManagerFactory**

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
                    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
                    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
                    </property>
                    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
                    <property name="jpaProperties">
                        <props>
                            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</prop> 
                                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">your schema</prop> -->
                   // your chice. 
                            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.oracle10gdialect</prop>
                            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLdialect</prop> -->


                            <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">4</prop>
                            <prop key="hibernate.connection.shutdown">true</prop>
                            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> 
                            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>

                        </props>
                    </property>


                    <property name="packagesToScan" value="your.dto" />

        </bean>
```